# Drawing rectangular commutative diagrams

Tags: math-mode, tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

I know how to create rectangular commutative diagrams for e.g

```
\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[r, "\phi"] \arrow[d, red]
& B \arrow[d, "\psi" red] \\
C \arrow[r, red, "\eta" blue]
& D
\end{tikzcd}
```

will create

[image]

But I want to draw the following

[image]

Please suggest how to do this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Same principle really. See the diagram as a 4×3 matrix. In the first row you have `KF'` in the second column, nothing in the first and third col. In the second row you have `K` and `F'` in the first and third column, respectively. In rows three and four, you have `K\cup F'` and `F` in the second column, and nothing in the first and third column.

There will be several possible ways of making the `||` on top of the lines. One way is to simply place a label with `||` on the lines, with `, "||"{anchor=center,sloped}`. Here `anchor=center` means the label is placed on top of the line, not next to the line (as is default), and `sloped` means the node is rotated to match the angle of the line.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
        & KF' 
          \arrow[dl, dash]
          \arrow[dr, dash, "||"{anchor=center,sloped}] \\
 K \arrow[dr, dash, "||"{anchor=center,sloped}] & & 
 F' \arrow[dl, dash] \\
        & K\cap F' \arrow[d, dash] \\
        & F
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\tikzset{
  doubleline/.style = {decoration = {markings, mark = at position 0.5 with { \node[transform shape, xscale = .9, yscale=.5] {//}; } }, postaction = {decorate} },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
 &  & KF' \arrow[lld,no head] \arrow[rrd, doubleline, no head] &  &  \\
K \arrow[rrd,  doubleline, no head] &  &  &  & F' \arrow[lld,  no head] \\
 &  & K\cap F' \arrow[d, no head] &  &  \\
 &  & F &  & 
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```